# How to add a bitmap to a view, then add that view to a viewgroup

Tags: android, view, bitmap, viewgroup

Maybe a simple question but i have an activity that retrieves a bitmap(camerashot) from a folder on the sdcard. The activity's custom view extends viewgroup. i'd like to add the bitmap to the view then add that view to the view group then display. eventually there will be multiple views added in this way. what are the best practices for this? for example would you get the activity to get the bitmap first, then in the viewgroup file access that bitmap with the following.

```
bitmap bm = (ActivityName()getContext()).methodToGetBitmap();
```

The bitmap can be added to a view, which inturn can be addeded to the viewgroup then displayed. thanks

[update] activity

```
public class HorizontalPagerActivity extends Activity {


    private static final String TAG = "*********hpActivity";
    private Context mContext = this;
    File tempFile;
    byte [] imageArray;
    private Bitmap b = null;

     @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



            setContentView(R.layout.hpview);
            final ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hpview); 




            tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                    getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"image.jpeg");

            imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];





         try{

                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


                int i = 0;

                while (dis.available() > 0 ) {
                imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
                i++;
                }

                dis.close();


           } catch (Exception e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
                }



           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length);
          // Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           b = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);

            if(b == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "b = null");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "b =  not null");
            }






             Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
             Log.e(TAG, "canvas created");




             View view = new View(this);
             Log.e(TAG, "view created");
             LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                view.draw(canvas);


             viewgroup.addView(view);
             Log.e(TAG, "view added to viewgroup");


             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    viewgroup.postInvalidate();
                }
            });

             Log.e(TAG, " inval called on viewgroup");

             Log.e(TAG, "no of chidren = "+viewgroup.getChildCount());





     }


}
```

the activity's view ia a viewgroup. so this is the parent view. the activity preprocesses the bitmap, creates and adds the views dynamically. it also calls invalidate on the parent viewgroup using runOnUiThread().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the parent view, and then dynamically append views to it.

Of course the activity would have to do the preprocessing and also append those views to the view group. Ideally this should be done in an AsyncTask, so that your activity can handle its current function. When the AsyncTask finshes, either use a handler to update the views/append or just run the update on the ui thread (runOnUIThread(...)).

Comment: thanks for reply. i've updated my post. is this along the right lines? it doesn't show the bitmap in the view. thanks

Comment: so all the views that i've added to the viewgroup dynamically will draw themselves after the call to invalidate on the ui thread? There's nothing i need to do in the viewgroup class, like override onDraw?

Comment: just another thought, i call view.draw(canvas); Would it be better if i set the bitmap to a drawable then use view.setBackgroundDrawable()?

Comment: depend on your situation you may have to just try it and see how you like it. Also dont forget to make it as your answer if you're technically done with this question :D!

Comment: i'm just looking for the standard way of doing it, the best practice. so if getting the parent view the dynamically adding the views in the activity before calling runOnUiThread is best practice, then i'll follow your advice. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change the view to an ImageView and the above code worked. so i think Jox's advice is correct....  Get the parent Viewgroup then dynamically add views to it. if an image then use imageview.